# How to install gem from GitHub source?

Tags: rubygems

I would like to install gem from the latest GitHub source.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 347, accepted):

In case you are using bundler, you need to add something like this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'redcarpet', :git => 'git://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet.git'
```

And in case there is `.gemspec` file, it should be able to fetch and install the gem when running `bundle install`.

**UPD.** As indicated in comments, for Bundler to function properly you also need to add the following to `config.ru`:

```
require "bundler" 
Bundler.setup(:default)
```

Comment: I also needed to add the following (added to my config.ru):
`require "bundler"
Bundler.setup(:default)`
See [bundler docs](http://gembundler.com/bundler_setup.html) for more details

Comment: Additionally one can specify ref, branch or tag options for example `gem 'redcarpet', :git => 'git://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet.git', :branch => 'yourbranch'`

Comment: there's also: `gem 'redcarpet', github: 'tanoku/redcarpet'`. http://akash.im/2012/06/05/bundler-new-github-option.html

Comment: @AmitPatel Thank you so so so much !!! :branch => 'yourbranch', your this line has solved a great problem for me just now. So much Grateful to you.

Comment: @gryzzly, how to specify tag for git?

Comment: @gaussblurinc `gem 'redcarpet', :git => 'git://github.com/tanoku/redcarpet.git', :tag => 'v2.3.5'` <- the `:tag => ''` part

Comment: In case you get the following warning replacing `git://` with `https://` solved it:
The git source `git://...` uses the `git` protocol, which transmits data without encryption. Disable this warning with `bundle config set --local git.allow_insecure true`, or switch to the `https` protocol to keep your data secure.

Answer (score 416):

That depends on the project in question. Some projects have a `*.gemspec` file in their root directory. In that case, it would be:

```
gem build GEMNAME.gemspec
gem install gemname-version.gem
```

Other projects have a rake task, called `gem` or `build` or something like that. In that case you have to invoke `rake <taskname>`, but that depends on the project.

In both cases you have to download the source.

Comment: Just a tip to let people know what it's really happening. The `gemname-version.gem` file is created when invoking `gem build`

Comment: Where does `gem install gemname-version.gem` command installs the git gem locally? I cannot find anywhere in my local machine an engine gem installed this way. Where does bundler hides it?

Comment: I think the `gem install gemname-version.gem` line should be `gem install --local gemname-version.gem`

Comment: @Green - `gem which gemname` should tell you where a specific gem is, does that not work for you?

Comment: Hi, I have only Rakefile and I have no clue how to install it. Any help?

Answer (score 284):

Try the [specific_install](https://github.com/rdp/specific_install) gem it allows you you to install a gem from its github repository (like 'edge'), or from an arbitrary URL. Very usefull for forking gems and hacking on them on multiple machines and such.

```
gem install specific_install
gem specific_install -l <url to a github gem>
```

e.g.

```
gem specific_install https://github.com/githubsvnclone/rdoc.git
```

Comment: could you add more explanation on the `specific_install` gem?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, similar to Python's pip git support. gem specific_install -l <url to project on github> worked like a charm!

Comment: `ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)    undefined method 'build' for Gem::Package:Module`  Sounds very cool but I won't be looking into it further. Just wanted to post that it didn't work for me in case someone else is about to give it a whirl based on SO recommendation.

Comment: @isomorphismes +1 to your comment.  I created a separate question about that error here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045874/error-when-running-gem-specific-install

Comment: Is there a way to specify branch to use? - Edit responding to myself, from the doc: "$ gem specific_install http://github.com/githubsvnclone/rdoc.git edge" or "$ gem specific_install -l http://github.com/githubsvnclone/rdoc.git -b edge"

Answer (score 43):

[Bundler](http://bundler.io/) allows you to use gems directly from git repositories.
In your Gemfile:

```ruby
# Use the http(s), ssh, or git protocol
gem 'foo', git: 'https://github.com/dideler/foo.git'
gem 'foo', git: 'git@github.com:dideler/foo.git'
gem 'foo', git: 'git://github.com/dideler/foo.git'

# Specify a tag, ref, or branch to use
gem 'foo', git: 'git@github.com:dideler/foo.git', tag: 'v2.1.0'
gem 'foo', git: 'git@github.com:dideler/foo.git', ref: '4aded'
gem 'foo', git: 'git@github.com:dideler/foo.git', branch: 'development'

# Shorthand for public repos on GitHub (supports all the :git options)
gem 'foo', github: 'dideler/foo'
```

For more info, see https://bundler.io/v2.0/guides/git.html

Comment: Please note that you might get in trouble if you use this approach with passenger and apache / ngix. When running `bundle`, such git-gem- dependencies will not be installed globally but in the current user's home directory instead. Passenger will run ruby as your web-server's user (e.g. `www-data`) which has no access to this directory and therefore this "git-gem" won't be loaded. You will get an error `... is not yet checked out. Run bundle install first`.

Answer (score 16):

OBSOLETE (see comments)

If the project is from github, and contained in the list on http://gems.github.com/list.html, then you can just add the github repo to the gems sources to install it :

```
$ gem sources -a http://gems.github.com
$ sudo gem install username-projectname
```

Comment: o rly? i just now did this and it DID work... go to gems.github.com before adding it to yr sources i guess? (but don't use sudo)

Comment: @esharp, they host the ones they built, but they don't build them anymore. If the gem got updated [since 2009](https://github.com/blog/500-state-of-the-hub-rackspace-day-0), a gems.github.com copy will be obsolete.

Answer (score 12):

If you are getting your gems from a public GitHub repository, you can use the shorthand

```
gem 'nokogiri', github: 'tenderlove/nokogiri'
```

Answer (score 4):

Also you can do `gem install username-projectname -s http://gems.github.com`

Comment: Obsolete, see the other answer's comments.

Comment: Still helped me for an issue with an old code base. Yes its 2013 and i am working on a rails 2.3.4 project.

Answer (score 3):

If you install using bundler as suggested by gryzzly and the gem creates a binary then make sure you run it with `bundle exec mygembinary` as the gem is stored in a bundler directory which is not visible on the normal gem path.

Answer (score 3):

In your Gemfile, add the following:

```
gem 'example', :git => 'git://github.com/example.git'
```

You can also add ref, branch and tag options,

For example if you want to download from a particular branch:

```
gem 'example', :git => "git://github.com/example.git", :branch => "my-branch"
```

Then run:

```
bundle install
```

Answer (score 2):

On a fresh Linux machine you also need to install `git`. Bundle uses it behind the scenes.