# Branch of a Gem is not installed correctly with Rails and Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

### Initial Problem

I was using `yaml_db` in a Rails project, but it seems the default branch has some issues with boolean records. Now I know that there's a [branch on github that has a fixed version](https://github.com/robsharp/yaml_db/tree/fix_boolean_checks_to_support_oracle).

I changed my Gemfile so that this branch will be installed instead of the default `yaml_db`,

```
gem 'yaml_db', :git => "https://github.com/robsharp/yaml_db.git"
```

I run `bundle install` and it shows:

> Using yaml_db (0.2.0) from https://github.com/robsharp/yaml_db.git (at master).
>
> Your bundle is complete! It was installed into /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0

Fine. Now the fixed [file in the Git repository](https://github.com/robsharp/yaml_db/commit/4085e6bc0e961fb783de9997d7e8c150e5887437) **should have this line** in `lib/serialization_helper.rb`:

```
record[column] = convert_boolean(record[column])
```

Yet, when I look at my local file, which is `.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/yaml_db-ca178cfb59cf/lib/serialization_helper.rb`, it still shows the **unpatched old line**:

```
record[column] = (record[column] == 't' or record[column] == '1')
```

Fine, seems as my local file isn't changed.

---

### Gem not being installed correctly

Running `gem list` won't show me `yaml_db` at all. I removed the Gem lockfile and installed the bundle again, still there is no `yaml_db` in my Gem listing. Running `gem install yaml_db` of course only installs the broken version.

---

### Manual Install

I now try to manually install from the Git source.

```
git clone https://github.com/robsharp/yaml_db.git
cd yaml_db
git checkout -b fix_boolean_checks_to_support_oracle
```

Still, the `serialization_helper.rb` file is not updated correctly. I just manually changed it and built the Gem. Everything works fine now.

My new question: **Why won't it check out the correct file?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run `gem list yaml_db` and see multiple versions in parenthesis, define the version you need in your Gemfile like so

```
gem 'yaml_db', '~> 0.2.0', :git => "https://github.com/robsharp/yaml_db.git"
```

I had a similar problem and found out that the `Gemfile.lock` file stored my old and not–updated version and used that for my project.

Comment: Listing showed me `*** LOCAL GEMS ***` and nothing else. I deleted the lockfile and ran `bundle install` again. No luck. Seems like it isn't even installed.

Comment: Yep, sure does. I sometimes forget to switch the ruby version before installing a Gem when using RVM. Maybe you've installed it somewhere else by accident?

Comment: I've never had problems with adding other Gems to my Gemfile and installing them. I use 1.9.2-p0 as default on the system. When I search for the `serialization_helper.rb` file, there's only one (the one that I'm referring to in the question)

Comment: Have you tried to leave the source away (given that you have added the source to your gem sources — gem sources -a http://gems.github.com )  and to run the install again? Does the gem show up if you just use gem list to show all your installed gems?

Comment: Hm... I've tried both with and without the source. There's no yaml_db in `gem list` at all.

Comment: Hmm… install using `gem install` maybe?

Comment: `gem install yaml_db` works, of course, but this is the buggy version. Can I specify that I want to install from the Git branch I mentioned above?

Comment: I guess you could use `gem install --source https://github.com/robsharp/yaml_db.git` or follow the instructions here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source and build the gem yourself.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to build it, but I had to patch the file myself since it didn't check out the correct file. Can you spot the problem? (I edited the original question)

Comment: Ah, so the fix was in a different branch? I guess it always installs from master…

Comment: Obviously it didn't use the correct branch, yes. Thank you so much for your patience.