# Cannot install specific version of Susy through ruby gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, susy-compass

I need to install [susy](https://github.com/ericam/susy) with gem. When I type

```
sudo gem install susy --version 0.9
```

It would result an error message:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'susy' (= 0.9) in any repository
```

However I have checked the source at github and the 0.9 tag does exist.

How can this happen? How to force rubygem to download those specific version instead of the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 0.9 version of the Susy gem was called `compass-susy-plugin`. What you want is:

```
gem install compass-susy-plugin
```

Answer (score 0):

When I run:

```
gem install susy --version 0.9 -V
```

I see that `gem` is going to rubygems.org for the gem in question.

*However* when I look for the `susy` gem on that server, all I find is version [1.0.1](http://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=susy).

In your Gemfile, you could try to specify the source of the gem from a git repo as they do in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source).

Normally, you'd put all of your gems you want to use in a Gemfile and then run `bundle install` from the directory that contains the Gemfile.