# show images in checkbox collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, best-in-place

I use best_in_place (it's not important for my question).

I want to show images instead of the checkbox.

my images are found in: `public/images`.

so I tried:

```
<%= best_in_place task, :done,:classes => 'highlight_on_success', type: :checkbox, collection: [image_tag("/images/checkbox_yes.gif"), image_tag("/images/checkbox_no.png")] %>
```

unfortunately, the default image of the checkbox (should be the first image) is shown as `-`, and when I press it, I saw the second image.

I tried to check if there is a problem with my first image, so I changed my code into:

```
<%= best_in_place task, :done,:classes => 'highlight_on_success', type: :checkbox, collection: [image_tag("/images/checkbox_no.png"), image_tag("/images/checkbox_yes.gif")] %>
```

But the default image (should be the second image) was shown as `-`, and when I pressed it, I saw the first image.

please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is addressed in [a recent pull request](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/pull/210), so update your `best_in_place` version to get this issue resolved. As can be seen from [the test code](https://github.com/guigs/best_in_place/commit/c668e6dc4db4cf071c4d833dfe6eda1cf245270b#L3R64) your syntax should be fine.

Comment: wow, I don't believe that I spent about 6 hours in order to solve it! how can I update my best_in_place? by 'bundle update'?

Comment: There is no release with this fix yet (2.0.2 is from 28 Nov), so use the version from Github: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source