# how to update best_in_place version from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

`gryzzly` is told me to update my best_in_place version from github, in order to solve this: [Checkboxes with images](https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place/pull/210)

He told to update from github, because there is no release with this fix yet.

so, I wrote in my `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'best_in_place', :git => 'git://github.com/bernat/best_in_place.git'
```

and then run: `bundle install`.

this is not fix my problem: [show-images-in-checkbox-collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14266858/show-images-in-checkbox-collection), so I think I did something wrong.

please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the branch you think is proper . In your case :

```
gem 'best_in_place', :git => 'git://github.com/bernat/best_in_place.git', :branch => 'fix-display-methods'
```

EDIT : Researching the commits , it appears that the correct entry in `Gemfile` is :

```
gem "best_in_place",:git => 'git://github.com/bernat/best_in_place.git', :tag => "0665b5f2e41967d8d1616f953fa3c0983cef1d51"
```

I hope this will solve your problem.

EDIT 2 : Today I've replicated your code on my machine and it works perfectly . The tag appears to be correct , only one slight thing in your code seems confusing : In Rails > 3 the reference to the image is simply `image_tag("your_img.png")` . Your code should be :

```
<%= best_in_place task, :done,:classes => 'highlight_on_success', type: :checkbox, collection: [image_tag("checkbox_no.png"), image_tag("checkbox_yes.png")] %>
```

Good luck .

Comment: I'm trying.
if you can, please tell me how can you find this tag. I want to know how to fix the same things next time :] thank you..

Comment: You should find the github place of the gem , in your case `https://github.com/bernat/best_in_place` and you look for `commits` tab . There is a chronology with meaningful labels of the commits . On the right of the commit , there is a clickable area , you click there and browse the commit code . There is a long combination of numbers and letters , which you use it in your Gemfile as `:tag` . Now I am sure you'll find the right commit and it's gonna be OK.

Comment: Ok, thank you.. I will try and hope to find it. thank you! (I will update this topic).