# How to avoid the source being overwritten when compiling a Gem?

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems, 64-bit, eventmachine

I am trying to install `eventmachine` Gem, however [a line needs to be commented out in the source](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/pull/411) for this to work on Ruby 2.0 on Windows x64.

I have tried modifying the Gem source in the Ruby build folder but each time I run `gem install eventmachine` it overwrites my changes. From the command line help there does not appear to be a way to rebuild the gem without unpacking fresh source, however there may be a workaround.

Is there a way to build my slightly tweaked source for this Gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't install the gem like that. Instead, build your own version and install that instead by specifying the path to the `.gem` file that is produced as part of the build process.

I've found the easiest way to get this right is to create a fork, set the fork's `git` path in your `Gemfile`, and `bundle install` which will take care of compiling things and installing them correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I'm pretty new to Ruby (I only have it on my computer to run AppFog's client). I tried making a file named `Gemfile` and including it in an arbitrary directory. It contains `gem 'eventmachine', :git => 'git://github.com/brendanarnold/eventmachine.git'`, in that directory I then run `gem install eventmachine`, however it still seems to be downloading the official source - am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Ah I didn't use `bundle` I used `gem`, that probably would work - however I got it working a different way, thanks anyway!

Comment: Yeah, I was trying to say that `gem install` always pulls from the canonical source unless you give it a path to a local `.gem` file. `bundle install` will do whatever's spelled out in your `Gemfile`, including custom builds.

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out thanks to help from @tadman.

Ended up just installing locally from source rather than tweaking the official source downloaded by `gem` and preventing it from being overwritten. These are the exact steps ...

- Clone locally from Github (or wherever)
- Make your changes to the source
- If there is a `.gemspec` file in the root directory

  - Open terminal in the directory and enter `gem build GEMNAME.gemspec`
  - Finally enter `gem install GEMNAME-VERSION.gem`
- If there is not `.gemspec` but there is a file called "gem" or "build" or something similar , then you may have to build using `rake` [according to this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source)

Comment: On a side note, the source compiled and installed the Gem but it turns out that it still did not work when actually using it in code. If anyone reading this is trying to install `eventmachine` on Windows x64, I found it easier in the end to switch to Ruby 1.9.3 32bit and work from there - eventmachine compiled straight away and now I can run the AppFog client ...