# Installing AppFog client on Windows x64 with Ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cloud-foundry, caldecott

I'm having a hard time installing the AppFog client Ruby Gem on my development machine. In particular to `tunnel` capability which requires `Caldecott`.

Here is what I have done so far,

- RubyInstaller install of Ruby 2.0 x64 (the only one on my computer, I've not really used Ruby before)
- `gem update --system`
- `gem install af`

This works ok for the `af login` etc.

- Installed the RubyInstaller DevKit
- Cloned `eventmachine` from GitHub and [patched and installed as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16310793/how-to-avoid-the-source-being-overwritten-when-compiling-a-gem)
- `gem install caldecott --platform=ruby`

This all works fine with no complaints from the Gem system, however now when I run the AppFog client I still get,

> C:\Ruby200-x64\bin>gem install caldecott --platform=ruby
>   Successfully installed caldecott-0.0.5 Parsing documentation for
>   caldecott-0.0.5 1 gem installed
>
> C:\Ruby200-x64\bin>af tunnel [WARNING] DL is deprecated, please use
>   Fiddle To use `af tunnel', you must first install Caldecott:
>
> ```
>     gem install caldecott
> ```
>
> Note that you'll need a C compiler. If you're on OS X, Xcode will
>   provide one. If you're on Windows, try DevKit.
>
> This manual step will be removed in the future.
>
> Error: Caldecott is not installed.
>
> C:\Ruby200-x64\bin>

i.e. the install doesn't recognise `caldecott`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It turns out that although `eventmachine` compiled and installed using the method described above, it still did not run when importing into Ruby code. As a result I blitzed the whole Ruby 2.0.0 install and and instead installed Ruby 1.9.3 33bit(?). This worked fine, eventmachine installed and so did Caldecott. I'll leave the question here for people who really must use Ruby 2.0.0 on Windows ...

Answer (score 0):

It says, you must intall Devkit : http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/
It's for the C compiler

Comment: I have Devkit installed

Comment: I couldn't tell you. I uninstalled Ruby 2.0 and installed Ruby 1.9.3 which worked. The DevKit is not in my path right now with the new version (which works fine), but I definitely had a DevKit version installed with 2.0 as well.

Comment: https://github.com/appfog/af/issues/27 , it seems that af don't work with ruby 2.0.0 whatever the OS