# How to install edited ruby gem from github on Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, rubygems

How can I install a ruby gem that I downloaded from github on my Amazon EC2 instance?

I want to change the code a little bit, this is why I cant install it directly via github.

Comment: Any reason why you cannot fork the gem on GitHub and install the fork (thus reducing the problem to [one that has already been solved](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2577346/78845))?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by fork the gem on GitHub? I want to make changes to the code of the gem..

Comment: You can read about how to [fork a repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo) on the GitHub site itself. Once you've created the fork, make your edits to the fork and then install from that source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **build gem** from installed source after some modifications and **install** it.
Just locate to source, find *mygem.gemspec* file, then `gem build mygem.gemspec` and `gem install mygem`.
Read more on http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/5.

Does it address your needs and solve your problem?