# Fetch and apply specific commit to local rubygem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems

I'm using the carrierwave gem in my app and in my Gemfile I have the line:

```
gem "carrierwave", "0.9.0"
```

Recently, a fix for i18n override problem with [Rails 4 was committed](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/1264), so what I want is to get **just** this *specific* commit and apply it to my local gem.

What steps should I follow to do this?

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge a specific commit in git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881092/how-to-merge-a-specific-commit-in-git) well at least I think the same principles are involved.

Comment: @Phlip this will fetch other commit in the master repository

Comment: @zwippie thank you for the link i already read this answer, but i'm new to github and i want a simple steps i know how to google when i have a problem, so this is the reason why i say i need steps one by one ...

Comment: @zwippie the post in your link you can see that in the answer, the guy have already knowledge he say : I have forked a branch from a repository it github and commit something for my using...., but in my case i don't know how to fork then commit this change ...

Comment: @medBo you must look up how to pass the hashtag of the specific version you want into gem. Try (literally) reading it's source, and look for where it reads the `:git =>` part.

Comment: @Phlip I'm new to git and github, i don't know how to do what you say, and this is why i ask the question here :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't just pick up a commit and apply it to your gem. However you can use the entire version on github instead of the version on rubygems.

```
gem 'carrierwave', git: 'git://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave.git', ref: '210d25c629ad24450b5d1f480a92e7500d8ed5b9'
```

The ref parameter is on the commit that fix i18n.

Comment: i think you are wrong about this :) read this proposition here : https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/pull/1229 before the last comment

Comment: look at this too : http://markosullivan.ca/how-to-handle-a-pull-request-from-github/  and  http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/04/pick-out-individual-commits.html

Comment: Of course you can fork the projet and cherry pick the commit. So if you already know that what was your question? :)

Comment: problem is i don't know how to do that :D imagine you are new to git and github and someone tell you, hi you should fork the projet and cherry pick the commit !!! this don't make sense to me :)