# How could I install Gems from git repositories?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I need to install gem form git repository. repository contains `.gemspec` file. In my gem file i have following code:

```
gem 'echo_server', :git => 'http://127.0.0.1/org/echo_server.git'
```

When i am running bundle install gems are installer in `.bundeler` and not showing in `gem list`.

my question is:
How the gem will be available in system, so that i can use in `require` ?

There are some similar [SOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source) but it does't help me.

Comment: only 'echo-server' gem is not shown in gem list or others too?

Comment: others gems which are installed from ruby gems are showing .

Answer (score 2):

It is not showing up when you type `gem list` because it is not being installed like a regular gem. You can `require` it like you would any other library because Bundler knows about it and will set it up for you. You should see it in your `$LOAD_PATH`:

```
$LOAD_PATH.grep(/nameofgem/)
```

See the [Bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.5/git.html) on this for more information.

If instead you want to install it as a regular gem from the Git repository, you can clone the repository and then build and install the generated gem. For example:

```
gem build echo_server.gemspec
gem install echo_server-X.Y.Z.gem
```

There is also [specific_install](https://github.com/rdp/specific_install).

Comment: Yes, if i use `gem bild`  then `bundle install` then it's working fine. But some how i need to automate it, by using only `bundle install`. Is there any way to achieve it?  there is nothing added in ruby $LOAD_PATH

Comment: As far as I am aware, Bundler can't be used to install a gem from a Git repository to the gem path like `gem install` would. You can see where Bundler installed the gem with `bundle show echo_server`. I also updated my answer to link to [specific_install](https://github.com/rdp/specific_install).

Comment: if i do 'bundle install' gem is installed in $BUNDLER_PATH. How could i use it in irb? irb> require 'echo_server' #=>  LoadError: cannot load such file. because irb looking for it in ruby home, but bundler installed it in bundler home.

Comment: Bundler needs to be loaded. In the same directory as your Gemfiles, try `bundle console` instead of `irb`. You can also do `require 'bundler'`, `Bundler.setup`, and `require 'echo_server'`, in that order. See [the Bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/) for more information.