# installing Twitter Bootstrap 3 gem from github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

There is a separate branch for the Twitter Bootstrap 3 gem.  I understand from this SO question [How to install gem from GitHub source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source) that  when installing a gem from github, the url should end in `.git` However, when I go to the github page for Twitter Bootstrap 3 gem, the cloning url is exactly the same for Twitter Bootstrap 3 as it is for the master branch (version 2)

```
 https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git
```

How to install Twitter bootstrap 3 gem from github?

Comment: Are you using Sass in your Rails app? I'm going with bootstrap-sass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a branch of a git repo in your `Gemfile` using the following syntax:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', github: 'seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails', branch: 'bootstrap3'
```

Comment: The answer was actually in the question you posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source/7421712#comment15319352_7421712

Comment: You can simplify this by using `github` instead of `git`. For example: `gem 'bootstrap', github: 'seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails', branch: 'bootstrap3'`

Comment: This declaration gives me a "Could not find gem 'bootstrap (>= 0) ruby' in git (...)" and i had to specify the 'complete' name of the gem:   gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', github: 'seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails', branch: 'bootstrap3'