# ruby klout gem include change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, klout

Currently I use `klout` gem in many times for all my projects. In the gem, there is:

```
Hash.send :include, Hashie::HashExtensions
```

hash extension include but I want to change it to:

```
Hash.send :include, Hashie::Extensions
```

How can I overwrite this line?

PS: I suggest you to check source code of the gem, especially [klout.rb](https://github.com/tatemae-consultancy/klout/blob/master/lib/klout.rb)

Answer (score 1):

You can fork the `klout` github repository, push commits with changes to your fork, and then use it [How to install gem from GitHub source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source)

For example, if you use `bundler`, you can write in Gemfile

```
gem 'klout', :git => 'git://github.com/tyrbo/klout.git', :branch => 'hashie_fix'
```

to use alredy existing [klout fork](https://github.com/tyrbo/klout/commits/hashie_fix) with a fix

Comment: What if other gems have klout dependency? Is there any solution for all gems that have klout gem dependency.

Comment: If you cannot contribute to klout gem itself, the only 'clean' option is to create your own version of it, and your own version of each gem that uses it (recursively).
You can also try some 'dirty' solution like

Comment: require 'hashie';

Hashie::HashExtensions = Hashie::Extensions;

require 'klout';