# Is it possible to specify multiple commands in `tmuxinator`'s `pre_window`?

Tags: tmux, tmuxinator

In `tmuxinator` config files, you can specify that multiple commands should be run in a single shell, e.g.:

```
windows:
  - logs:
    - cd ~/project/log
    - tail -f db.log
```

Can you do the same with `pre_window`? The following things have not worked:

1.

```
pre_window:
  - cmd1
  - cmd2
```

2.

```
pre_window: [ cmd1,
  cmd ]
```

3.

```
pre_window:
  - a: cmd1
  - b: cmd2
```

I may be missing something fairly simple; I don't know YAML very well or understand `tmuxinator`'s implementation much.

I already know about (and am currently using)

```
pre_window: cmd1 && cmd2
```

What I'd like is for `tmuxinator` to send each line separately.

Comment: https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/pull/482

Comment: @ramirio thank you for the link. Post it as an answer with, like, a sentence-long writeup and I'll accept it.

Comment: done, i hope they merge  this PR as soon as possible :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>Currently there is a [pull request](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/pull/482) for these feature in the tmuxinator repository.

You can fetch the pull request locally (maybe using [git-extras](https://github.com/tj/git-extras/blob/master/Commands.md#git-pr)) and [build the gem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2577404/1405326) while they don't merge it.</s>

They merged the PR and this feature [is in the new release](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/releases/tag/v0.10.0).