# How to install gem from Github source using RVM

Tags: github, rubygems, rvm

I'm looking to install a gem from a Github repo by using RVM, not bundler and am a little confused about the process. Do I create a gemset first? Sorry if this is an easy fix or a repeat.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the project has a `*.gemspec` file in the root directory, you can clone the repo locally and then perform the following

```
gem build GEMNAME.gemspec
gem install gemname-version.gem
```

The `gemname-version.gem` file is created when invoking `gem build`. If there is no `*.gemspec` file, then look for instructions on how to build the gem locally - most gem projects on Github will describe how to do this in the README.

You don't need to create a Gemset within RVM if you don't need it.

#### EDIT

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source) Stackoverflow post for additional information and alternative approaches.

Comment: Thanks so much! Sorry, I actually saw the first post but assumed the answers were all pertaining to bundler installs.