# Get gem file from github using bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, twitter-bootstrap, bundler

I am trying to use [bootstrap-fileinput](https://github.com/kartik-v/bootstrap-fileinput)
 in a rails project.I found a github repository which seems to have it in gem form but i dont know how to use it.

```
gem 'rails-bootstrap-fileinput', :git => 'https://github.com/atalargo/rails-bootstrap-fileinput.git'
```

in **Gemfile** failed.
Is this usable as a gem?
If not what do i need to do to use it?
Link to Github repository of the gem(supposedly) is in above code used in Gemfile...

Answer (score 1):

The gem name is incorrect. Try

```
gem 'bootstrap_fileinput', :git => 'https://github.com/atalargo/rails-bootstrap-fileinput.git'
```

In the future, refer to the gems' .gemspec files to sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting your gems from a public GitHub repository, you can use the shorthand

> gem 'nokogiri', :github => 'tenderlove/nokogiri'

Refer [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source/25696921#25696921)