# How to set up pocketsphinx-ruby of watsonbox?

Tags: pocketsphinx

I downloaded pocketsphinxbase_5realaplha and pocketsphinx_5realaplha  at cmusphinx. But I don't know how to set up pocketsphinx-ruby, which can't understand these file. How can I use it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install gem from GitHub source?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577346/how-to-install-gem-from-github-source)